# Shell script to CRON that calls URL and saves file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

Manually I enter an URL on a browser that calls a page that has a GET function that directly prompts me to save a file.
I would like to automate with a cron job on a script this actions:

- Call the URL
- Save the file in a specific folder

Anyone can help to write the script? I can privately provide the URL so to test the behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

One way to download an URL without having to use an user interface (text or GUI) is to use `wget` with all needed parameters (as you wish) as a cron job.

### About wget

An example for a single URL (with output name merged with a timestamp, to enrich the answer, could be a static name):

```
 wget URL -O "/home/uname/dirn/`date +%y%m%d-%H%M%S`-n.htm" -b
 wget URL -O "/home/uname/dirn/`date +\%y\%m\%d-\%H\%M\%S`-n.htm" -b #in crontab
```

note: in cron you have to use "\%" (as in the second line above) instead of just "%"  (as in the first line above), because cron interprets the "percent"-character.

where: `-O "/home..../date...-theRestOfTheName"` breaks up into:

- absolute path (cron may have its own path configured, so from practical point of view, it is often favourable to have your path of interest specified in each command)
- on-the-fly execution of `date` with output configured as a human-readable kind-of a time-stamp
- the rest of the target file name

`-b` asks wget do work in the background, with logging into syslog.

You can optionally use a list of URLs from a file (`-i filename`).  You could also play around with wget and its manpage (`man wget`) - it is relatively short and can give you lots of ideas.

### About cron

Note, cron assusmes your machine is on at all times: cron does not catch up with jobs for the time the machine was off. Editing cron as a current user

```
crontab -e
```

Add a line of configuration that specifies the frequency of execution of the command (simple instruction gets displayed as a comment in the topmost lines the crontab editor, please read it).  For running every 5 minutes on Sunday you would write:

```
# m  h  dom mon dow   command
*/5  *   *   *   0    wget google.com -O "/home/uname/dirn/`date +\%y\%m\%d-\%H\%M\%S`-ind3.htm" -b
```

Comment: @steeldriver - you are absolutely right about the need for escaping of "%" in the crontab. I made the corrections.